# Issue with COALESCE in DB2 and Jasper Reports

Tags: java, sql, jasper-reports, db2, coalesce

I am having a query wherein I am fetching out sum of a column from a table formed through sub query.

Something in the lines:

```
select temp.mySum as MySum from (select sum(myColumn) from mySchema.myTable) temp;
```

However, I don't want MySum to be null when temp.mySum is null. Instead I want MySum to carry string 'value not available' when temp.mySum is null.

Thus I tried to use coalesce in the below manner:

```
select coalesce(temp.mySum, 'value not available') as MySum from (select sum(myColumn) from mySchema.myTable) temp;
```

However above query is throwing error message:

```
Message: The data type, length or value of argument "2" of routine "SYSIBM.COALESCE" is incorrect.
```

This message is because of datatype incompatibility between argument 1 and 2 of coalesce function as mentioned in the first answer below.

However, I am directly using this query in Jasper to send values to Excel sheet report:

```
hashmap.put("myQuery", this.myQuery);
JasperReport jasperReportOne = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(this.reportJRXML);
JasperPrint jasperPrintBranchCd = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReportOne , hashmap, con);
jprintList.add(jasperPrintOne);
JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();
exporterXLS.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jprintList);
exporterXLS.exportReport();
```

In the excel sheet, I am getting value as null when the value is not available. I want to show 'value unavailable' in the report.

How could this be achieved ?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments to coalesce must be compatible. That's not the case if the first is numeric (as `mySum` probably is) and the second is a string.

For example, the following [PubLib doco](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref/rch2bas.htm) has a table indicating compatibility between various types, at least for the DB2 I work with (the mainframe one) - no doubt there are similar restrictions for the iSeries and LUW variants as well.

You can try something like `coalesce(temp.mySum, 0)` instead or convert the first argument to a string with something like `char()`. Either of those should work since they make the two arguments compatible.

Comment: Yes, `COALESCE( CHAR(temp.mysum), 'value not available')` will provide the desired result on DB2 LUW